# How to Vary Dot Size in dotchart() in R

Tags: r, charts, size, vary

I have a question on creating a dotchart using the following data:

```
    Patient ID Day Dosage of Drug (mg)
     1552        1     .3
     1552        7     .8
     1552       14    1.2
     1663        1     .2
     1663        7     .7
     1663       18    1.4
```

I can create the dotchart with the x-axis as "day" and y-axis as each patient so that for Patient ID 1552, there are three points at days 1, 7, and 14. No problems there. But now I want to make it so that the dot sizes are proportional to the amount of dosage taken on that day so that the dot on day 14 will be larger than 7 and 1 on the same Patient ID line. Is there any way I can do this?

I know the `dotchart()` function has a modifiable `cex` element that changes the y-axis font/dot size but it does so uniformly. Is there any way of plotting each point separately and each time making the dot size a different size according to the Dose data?

Comment: What happens when you pass a vector to cex?

Answer (score 1):

I would create such a chart using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(aes(x = day, y = patient, size = dosage), data = df) + 
      geom_point()
```

Where I assume the data.frame with the data is called `df`, and that it contains the columns named day, patient, and dosage.

Comment: oh man, that worked great. I modified the ggplot slightly after taking a look at a ggplot tutorial and went with geom_point(aes(size = dosage)). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mind ticking an answer as the correct answer? That way people get some reputation, and everyone can see your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `ggplot2` package, you can do it like this:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("ID Day Dose
     1552        1     .3
     1552        7     .8
     1552       14    1.2
     1663        1     .2
     1663        7     .7
     1663       18    1.4"), header=TRUE)    

require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(factor(Day), factor(ID)))
p + geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", binpositions="all") + 
 geom_point(aes(size=Dose))
```

[image]